# IndexOutOfRange when it's clearly not

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

Sorry the title isn't really describing the issue, but it's a very weird one.

To make sure I wasn't doing any idiotic mistakes, I use breakpoints to track everything that was happening..

Basically, I have this code in a class which inherits from `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
var n = new MyClass();
int startIndex = 0; // parameter
int length = 2;  // parameter

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    n.Text += this[startIndex].Text;
    this.RemoveAt(startIndex);
}

this.Insert(n);
```

When executing the code, my collection has 3 items ; the loop goes like this:

1. `n.Text += "some string successfully gotten from this[startIndex]"`
2. `this.RemoveAt(startIndex)`
3. `n.Text += "some other string successfully gotten from this[startIndex]"`
4. **Exception: IndexOutOfRange.**

I'm successfully getting the item, and yet there is an error when I'm trying to delete it. I'm lost here.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

### EDIT 1

I've tried this, and had the same result.

```
var toRemove = this.Skip(startIndex).Take(length).ToList();

foreach (var b in toRemove)
{
    this.Remove(b);
    n.Text += b.Text;
}
```

Once again, I have an **IndexOutOfRange** Exception when `Removing` an item.
Whilst debugging, my Collection has 2 items, and `RemoveAt(0)` still throws this Exception.

### EDIT 2

I tried to manually call `OnCollectionChanged` when modifying `this.Items`. The **IndexOutOfRange** Exception is triggered when calling `OnCollectionChanged`, but not when removing the item from `this.Items`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, Items[startIndex], startIndex));
    Items.RemoveAt(startIndex);
}
```

After calling `this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))`, I also have a problem.
Looks like the whole problem comes from the ListBox. I'll try playing with the Bindings, and other things, and report.

Comment: How many items in collection when exception is thrown?

Comment: Is `startIndex` always 0? Do you update it somewhere?

Comment: `startIndex` isn't always zero, but it never changes within the method. The `Count` check is done before doing all this.

Comment: There must be some interaction with another piece of code, because I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Yes, I figured something else caused an issue, but I can't find anything (except maybe a ListBox) "linked" to the Collection somewhat. I don't override any method, nor subscribe to any of its events.

Comment: @Greg - Please post all relevant code. So if `startIndex` changes somewhere you should show it. In fact the code you post should be something we can run that reproduces the problem for us. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Enigmativity `startIndex` never changes. It is a parameter given to the method. I don't think anything else is truly relevant.

Comment: Post the full exception ToString.

Comment: @Greg - You should focus on providing enough code for us to reproduce your issue. If you don't know what's going wrong with your code how are you meant to know what's relevant?

Comment: @Enigmativity I understand this, but I would've had to provide hundred of lines of code to include the original problem.

Comment: @Greg - I'm not trying to be difficult, but then you should have post all the code, or not posted at all, or reduced the code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. You're a new user here - I'm just trying to let you know what works best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I feel bad.

Basically, `SelectionChanged` was triggered everytime the `ObservableCollection` changed, trying to do some stuff and encountering an error. The thing is, nothing in the Stacktrace led to that idea.

Sorry for wasting your time (considering how the comments / answers were good), and keep going.

Answer (score 0):

1. I wouldn't recommend to write `this.RemoveAt(startIndex);` in the loop, sometimes it's not ok when observable collection enumeration changes inside the loop, so I would get it out of the loop definitely
2. Seems like you've realized your own realization of Insert for Obs.Coll. maybe the issue is there

**UPD**

I think your problem in bad design. you said your class inherits from observable collection, what is this then ? try better design and define method outside of collection class, as it pretends that your collection is 3 elems at least ALL THE TIME

**UPD 2**

Design is still ugly, but in case you want to stick with it, here what I did and it worked :

1. Your collection definition (NOT RECOMMEND DOING IT THIS WAY)

   ```
   public class MyObs : ObservableCollection<MyClass> {
     public void Fun() {
         var n = new MyClass();
         int startIndex = 0; // parameter
         int length = 2;  // parameter

         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             n.Text += this [startIndex].Text;
             this.RemoveAt(startIndex);
         }

         this.Insert(0,n); // PAY ATTENTION THAT I INSERT AT 0 !
     }
   }

   public class MyClass {
     public string Text { get; set; }

     public override string ToString() {
         return Text;
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then your XAML:

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}"/>
   ```
3. Then your declaration code:

   ```
   public MyObs MyCollection { get; set; }
   ```
4. Then initialization and processing:

   ```
   MyCollection = new MyObs();
   MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() {Text = "Item 1"});
   MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() { Text = "Item 2" });
   MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() { Text = "Item 3" });

   MyCollection.Fun();
   ```

[image]

**seems like your problem in your Insert**

Comment: Yes, it could have been this. But I haven't overriden anything, or subscribed to any event of the ``ObservableCollection``. I have also tried Removing out of the loop, to no success.

Comment: (Response to the **UPD**) Yes, it has some bad design for now, but (I know nobody will trust me) I plan to change it later. Right now, the ObservableCollection isn't the problem, but the ListBox is. The method I'm calling always checks if there are more than 2 elements before executing.

Comment: Cause your design is about it. So change it now and it's gonna work. Also you may mark my reply as answer ;)

Comment: I still _don't_ understand. Does the fact that my class inherit `ObservableCollection<T>` cause all those errors?

Comment: Yes I def-ly think so, have some spare minutes will check it and update answer, so I create class inheriting from OC and bind it to ListBox right ? @Greg

Comment: I'm going to look into this. This is great work, thank you very much.

Comment: @Greg would appreciate if you mark this as answer etc

Comment: I did find the solution though. It was a stupid mistake of mine. I'm sorry you spent so much time for nothing, and would've loved to give you some sweet reputation (you **do** deserve it), but this is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is about you´re referecing a removed index here:

```
var toRemove = this.Skip(startIndex).Take(length).ToList();
foreach (var b in toRemove)
{
    this.Remove(b);        <<<  removed
    n.Text += b.Text;      <<<  referencing the removed
}
```

This way, obviously you have the error described. Invert the order from n.text and the remove.

Comment: I tried both solutions. Notice `ToList()`, which "breaks" the reference. `toRemove` doesn't change, unlike the collection in `this`.